# How to handle a long request with Express

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, async-await, request

I'm working on a simple function I have for a specific GET request triggered in the browser. The objective of this request is to make multiple queries to a mongodb (mongoose) database and then perform some calculation and structure formating on the results to send it back to the browser. 
The only problem is that everything takes too long and it results in an error in the browser:

> net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

to give an example of part of the function I'm trying to build here it goes:

```
async function getPriceByMake(makes, id) { 
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        let pMakes = {};
        const makesArr = Object.keys(makes);
        for (let i = 0; i < makesArr.length; i++) {
            console.log('Getting the docs ... ' + Math.round(i/makesArr.length*100) + '%')
            const currMake = makesArr[i];
            pMakes[currMake] = {};
            const modelsArr = Object.keys(makes[currMake]);
            for (let j = 0; j < modelsArr.length; j++) {
                const currModel = modelsArr[j];
                await Listing.find({ catFrom: id, model: currModel }, 'year asking', (err, docs) => {
                    if (docs.length > 1) { 
                        pMakes[currMake][currModel] = [docs];
                    } else {
                        pMakes[currMake][currModel] = {};
                    }
                });
            }
        }
        resolve(pMakes);
    });
}
```

In this function, if I leave the `async / await` out, I get an empty `{}` on the other end. Which is obviously not the objective.

I've been searching the web a little and was able to find an [article](https://www.west-wind.com/presentations/wwAsyncWebRequest/wwAsyncWebRequest.htm) pointing to this scheme:

**Browser**:

- Initiates request
- displays progress
- Show result

**WebServer:**

- Submit event
- Checks for completion
- Return result

**BackEndApp:**

- Picks up event
- Runs task
- Returns results

My question is the following: 
**How can I do that with NodeJS and Express?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this code:

```
        for (let j = 0; j < modelsArr.length; j++) {
            const currModel = modelsArr[j];
            await Listing.find({ catFrom: id, model: currModel }, 'year asking', (err, docs) => {
                if (docs.length > 1) { 
                    pMakes[currMake][currModel] = [docs];
                } else {
                    pMakes[currMake][currModel] = {};
                }
            });
        }
```

Your `await` isn't working because you're passing a callback to `Listing.find()`.  When you do that, it does NOT return a promise and therefore the `await` does nothing useful.  You get the empty response because the `await` doesn't work and thus you call `resolve()` before there's any actual data there.

Change the code to this:

```
        for (let j = 0; j < modelsArr.length; j++) {
            const currModel = modelsArr[j];
            let docs = await Listing.find({ catFrom: id, model: currModel }, 'year asking');
            if (docs.length > 1) { 
                pMakes[currMake][currModel] = [docs];
            } else {
                pMakes[currMake][currModel] = {};
            }
        }
```

And, then the `await` will work properly.

You also should remove the `return new Promise()` wrapper.  You don't want that.  Just make the function `async` and use `await` and it will already return a promise.

Here's your function with the unnecessary promise wrapper removed:

```
async function getPriceByMake(makes, id) { 
    let pMakes = {};
    const makesArr = Object.keys(makes);
    for (let i = 0; i < makesArr.length; i++) {
        console.log('Getting the docs ... ' + Math.round(i/makesArr.length*100) + '%')
        const currMake = makesArr[i];
        pMakes[currMake] = {};
        const modelsArr = Object.keys(makes[currMake]);
        for (let j = 0; j < modelsArr.length; j++) {
            const currModel = modelsArr[j];
            let docs = await Listing.find({ catFrom: id, model: currModel }, 'year asking');
            if (docs.length > 1) { 
                pMakes[currMake][currModel] = [docs];
            } else {
                pMakes[currMake][currModel] = {};
            }
        }
    }
    return pMakes;
}
```

Then, keep in mind that whatever code sends your actual response needs to use `.then()` or `await` when calling this `async` function in order to get the final result.

---

Your best bet to speed up this code would be to refactor either your queries or your database structure or both to not have to do N * M separate queries to get your final result.  That's likely where your slowness is coming from.  The biggest performance gains will probably come from reducing the number of queries you have to run here to far fewer.

Depending upon your database configuration and capabilities, it might speed things up to run the inner loop queries in parallel as shown here:

```
async function getPriceByMake(makes, id) { 
    let pMakes = {};
    const makesArr = Object.keys(makes);
    for (let i = 0; i < makesArr.length; i++) {
        console.log('Getting the docs ... ' + Math.round(i/makesArr.length*100) + '%')
        const currMake = makesArr[i];
        pMakes[currMake] = {};
        const modelsArr = Object.keys(makes[currMake]);
        await Promise.all(modelsArr.map(async currModel => {
            let docs = await Listing.find({ catFrom: id, model: currModel }, 'year asking');
            if (docs.length > 1) { 
                pMakes[currMake][currModel] = [docs];
            } else {
                pMakes[currMake][currModel] = {};
            }
        }));
    }
    return pMakes;
}
```

Comment: Hey @jfriend00! Thanks for your answer. Your code looks a lot simplier / better than mine and I actually tried to implement it to the rest of the function but now my backend is executing even slower. Note that it doesn't matter much that it's slower, what matters to me is how can I execute that in the backend while my webserver / browser get updated of the status ?

Comment: @Ardzii - Well, http doesn't really communicate partial results.  One way people do that is by sending partial results over a webSocket or socket.io connection, but that significantly complicates things.

Comment: @Ardzii - I would suggest that maybe you need to improve the way you're using your database so you're not doing N * M separate queries.  I don't know your database structure or what the real problem you're trying to solve here is, but I would hope there's a database structure and a query structure that could get your desired result in a lot fewer queries.  That's probably where most of the time is being taken.

Comment: @Ardzii - Also, depending upon your database configuration, it may help to do many requests in parallel since each query seems independent from the others.   You could do all the queries from the inner loop in parallel and `await` only  the final results of all of them before the next outer loop iteration.

Comment: @Ardzii - I added a code example (to the end of my answer) of running the inner loop queries in parallel.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your follow-up and help! I totally had forgotten about `Promise.all`. That helped speed things up a little however it's still very slow. You're right, I need to review my queries and, as a matter of fact, I could simply make a gross query and work on all the results in the browser but I'd rather keep this information on the server rather than the client side...